# Python file crashes

Tags: python

(This is a question I found that wasn't answered @goonys)

Just started my first comp sci class this summer and need some help.

Our assignment is to make a stock transaction program (irrelevant), and im having trouble with 2 things. Whenever I open my .py file from the file explorer, it crashes after the 6th input. Whenever I run it from the cmd directly (python "file name") or in IDLE it works fine so I am confused.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code and and what it looks like in CMD. [code][2]

```
# This program will be used to determine
# Calculations for a stock transaction

# The inputs
Shares_Bought = int(input('Enter shares purchased: '))
SharePrice_B = float(input('Enter purchase price of shares: '))
B_Commission = float(input('Enter broker buy commission: '))
Shares_Sold = int(input('Enter shares sold: '))
SharePrice_S = float(input('Enter sell price of shares: '))
S_Commission = float(input('Enter broker sell comission: '))

#CONSTANTS?
TOTAL_PURCHASE = Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B
TOTAL_SALE = Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S
TOTAL_SALES_COMMISSION = (Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B) * (B_Commission / 100) + (Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S) * (S_Commission / 100)



# The outputs 
print('Alex Partida Stock Transaction App')
print(f'Joe Paid: ${Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B:,.2f}')
print(f'Purchase Commission: ${(Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B) * (B_Commission / 100):,.2f}')        # Need to make this shorter/split into more lines
print(f'Joe sold at: ${Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S:,.2f}')
print(f'Sales Commission: ${(Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S) * (S_Commission / 100):,.2f}')
print(f"Joe's Profit: ${(TOTAL_SALE - TOTAL_PURCHASE) - TOTAL_SALES_COMMISSION:,.2f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when a python file completes its code, it quits. In cmd and an ide, this is no problem as the program continues to run and shows you the output. But if we run the file standalone, the file will quit after it has run its code as there isn't anything left for it to do. Use a simple
`input("Press enter to exit...")`
to achieve the same effect the professor did in this scenario

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).